# How to upload image to Laravel storage?

Tags: laravel, routes, storage, laravel-storage

I'm trying to implement this [guide](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-image-upload-tutorial/) on how to upload an image to the `laravel storage` but when I submit, it shows that the page is expired. There is not error report in the `log` which makes it difficult to debug.

**`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/upload-image', [StorageController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/save', [StorageController::class, 'save']);
```

**`StorageController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Image;
use App\Models\Photo;



class StorageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('image');
    }

    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public');

        $save = new Photo;
        $save->name = $name;
        $save->path = $path;
        $save->save();

        return redirect('upload-image')->with('status', 'Image Has been uploaded');
    }
}
```

Model **`Photo.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Laravel view to upload the image **`image.blade.php`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Laravel 8 Uploading Image</title>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    @if(session('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
      </div>
    @endif
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">
        <h2>Laravel 8 Upload Image Tutorial</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image" action="{{ url('/save') }}" >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Choose image" id="image">
                @error('image')
                <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I navigate to `localhost/upload-image` it shows the view and I can choose a `file` in the input form but as soon as I click on the submit button, the page navigates to `/save` and shows `419 | Page Expired` with no log entry. The browser console shows:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/save 419 (unknown status)
```

Comment: Can you please pass in request csrf 
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image" action="{{ url('/save') }}" >
    @csrf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing @csrf token in form request:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image" action="{{ url('/save') }}" >
@csrf
```

Please pass as per above code example then it will be work.

Comment: Thanks! Now the controller uploads the image into the `storage` as well as creating an entry in the database

Answer (score 0):

You should include `@csrf` in your form tags.

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image" action="{{ url('/save') }}" >
@csrf
</form>
```

Comment: This answer was already given…